# Pushing a column to another row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, multiple-columns, grid-layout, multirow

So here's what I have in a LG design.

```
    +-----+-----+
    |  A  |  B  |
    +-----+-----+
    |  C  |  D  |
    +-----+-----+
```

I want to reorder it in a MD design to look like this:

```
    +---------+---------+
    |         A         |
    +---------+---------+
    | C   |   D  |  B   |
    +-------------------+
```

Is there a way for me to push "B" from the first row to the second, in that position? :)

Comment: Didn't test it but for A : col-md-12 and for B : col-md-push-X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```css
.row div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">A</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-md-push-8 col-lg-push-0">B</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-md-pull-4 col-lg-pull-0">C</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-md-pull-4 col-lg-pull-0">D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

By adding the class `col-md-12` to the column A, it will take up the whole row and column B will flow to the next row. However, it will appear on the left side. If you want it to appear on the right side, you have to specifiy the `col-*-pull-*` and `col-*-push-*` classes.

Comment: That's it. It worked. I didn't know I could use more than 12 cols in a row... Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy and can be accomplished by defining classes "col-md-n col-lg-n  col-md-push-m col-lg-push-m" (where n= no. of cols you want to display on md or a lg screen, m is a col count for push,pull classes). Check this snippet. Switch to full page and zoom in out to see the changes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 text-center" style="border:1px dashed pink;">
      <h1>A</h1>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4  col-md-push-8 col-lg-push-0 text-center" style="border:1px dashed pink;">
        <h1>B</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-md-pull-4 col-lg-pull-0 text-center" style="border:1px dashed pink;">
        <h1>C</h1>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  
    </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-md-pull-4 col-lg-pull-0 text-center" style="border:1px dashed pink;">
        <h1>D</h1>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does not fit the requierement of the op.

Comment: Kindly, switch to full page and zoom in out to see the changes.

Comment: ... Does the B section goes to the right ? Please, switch to full page and zoom in and out to see the changes.

Comment: Yes it does, just fixed it. Please check again.

Comment: @Guillaume Beauvois . As this has been fixed, you can take down your negative vote for the answer.